# Как установить dlib?

Tags: python

При использовании команды:

```
pip install dlib
```

Выдает ошибку:

```
"c:\users\eezbe\appdata\local\programs\thonny\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
self.run_command(cmd)
File "c:\users\eezbe\appdata\local\programs\thonny\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
cmd_obj.run()
File "c:\users\eezbe\appdata\local\programs\thonny\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
return orig.install.run(self)
File "c:\users\eezbe\appdata\local\programs\thonny\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 545, in run
self.run_command('build')
File "c:\users\eezbe\appdata\local\programs\thonny\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
self.distribution.run_command(command)
File "c:\users\eezbe\appdata\local\programs\thonny\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
cmd_obj.run()
File "c:\users\eezbe\appdata\local\programs\thonny\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
self.run_command(cmd_name)
File "c:\users\eezbe\appdata\local\programs\thonny\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
self.distribution.run_command(command)
File "c:\users\eezbe\appdata\local\programs\thonny\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
cmd_obj.run()
File "C:\Users\eezbe\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-kcgx0v3t\dlib\setup.py", line 135, in run
self.build_extension(ext)
File "C:\Users\eezbe\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-kcgx0v3t\dlib\setup.py", line 172, in build_extension
subprocess.check_call(cmake_setup, cwd=build_folder)
File "c:\users\eezbe\appdata\local\programs\thonny\lib\subprocess.py", line 363, in check_call
raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\\Users\\eezbe\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-kcgx0v3t\\dlib\\tools\\python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\eezbe\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-kcgx0v3t\\dlib\\build\\lib.win32-3.7', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c:\\users\\eezbe\\appdata\\local\\programs\\thonny\\python.exe', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\\Users\\eezbe\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-kcgx0v3t\\dlib\\build\\lib.win32-3.7']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
—--------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\eezbe\appdata\local\programs\thonny\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\eezbe\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-kcgx0v3t\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\eezbe\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-kcgx0v3t\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install —record 'C:\Users\eezbe\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-6joaylx3\install-record.txt' —single-version-externally-managed —compile —install-headers 'c:\users\eezbe\appdata\local\programs\thonny\Include\dlib' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Как я могу это исправить?

---

UPD

```
Collecting dlib
  Using cached dlib-19.20.0.tar.gz (3.2 MB)
Using legacy setup.py install for dlib, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: dlib
    Running setup.py install for dlib ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\eezbe\appdata\local\programs\thonny\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\eezbe\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-izoqttv6\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\eezbe\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-izoqttv6\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\eezbe\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-4ohgzi59\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\eezbe\appdata\local\programs\thonny\Include\dlib'
         cwd: C:\Users\eezbe\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-izoqttv6\dlib\
    Complete output (65 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    package init file 'dlib\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
    running build_ext
    Building extension for Python 3.7.7 (tags/v3.7.7:d7c567b08f, Mar 10 2020, 09:44:33) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]
    Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake C:\Users\eezbe\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-izoqttv6\dlib\tools\python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\eezbe\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-izoqttv6\dlib\build\lib.win32-3.7 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c:\users\eezbe\appdata\local\programs\thonny\python.exe -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\Users\eezbe\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-izoqttv6\dlib\build\lib.win32-3.7'
    -- Building for: Visual Studio 16 2019
    -- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.26.28806.0
    -- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.26.28806.0
    -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.26.28801/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
    -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.26.28801/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - works
    -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
    -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
    -- Detecting C compile features
    -- Detecting C compile features - done
    -- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.26.28801/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
    -- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.26.28801/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - works
    -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
    -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
    -- Detecting CXX compile features
    -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
    -- Found PythonInterp: C:/Users/eezbe/AppData/Local/Programs/Thonny/python.exe (found version "3.7.7")
    CMake Error at C:/Users/eezbe/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-izoqttv6/dlib/dlib/external/pybind11/tools/FindPythonLibsNew.cmake:124 (message):
      Python config failure: Python is 32-bit, chosen compiler is 64-bit
    Call Stack (most recent call first):
      C:/Users/eezbe/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-izoqttv6/dlib/dlib/external/pybind11/tools/pybind11Tools.cmake:16 (find_package)
      C:/Users/eezbe/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-izoqttv6/dlib/dlib/external/pybind11/CMakeLists.txt:33 (include)


    -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
    See also "C:/Users/eezbe/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-izoqttv6/dlib/build/temp.win32-3.7/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\eezbe\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-izoqttv6\dlib\setup.py", line 261, in <module>
        'Topic :: Software Development',
      File "c:\users\eezbe\appdata\local\programs\thonny\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "c:\users\eezbe\appdata\local\programs\thonny\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "c:\users\eezbe\appdata\local\programs\thonny\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "c:\users\eezbe\appdata\local\programs\thonny\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\eezbe\appdata\local\programs\thonny\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "c:\users\eezbe\appdata\local\programs\thonny\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 545, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "c:\users\eezbe\appdata\local\programs\thonny\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\users\eezbe\appdata\local\programs\thonny\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\eezbe\appdata\local\programs\thonny\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "c:\users\eezbe\appdata\local\programs\thonny\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\users\eezbe\appdata\local\programs\thonny\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\eezbe\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-izoqttv6\dlib\setup.py", line 135, in run
        self.build_extension(ext)
      File "C:\Users\eezbe\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-izoqttv6\dlib\setup.py", line 172, in build_extension
        subprocess.check_call(cmake_setup, cwd=build_folder)
      File "c:\users\eezbe\appdata\local\programs\thonny\lib\subprocess.py", line 363, in check_call
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\\Users\\eezbe\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-izoqttv6\\dlib\\tools\\python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\eezbe\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-izoqttv6\\dlib\\build\\lib.win32-3.7', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c:\\users\\eezbe\\appdata\\local\\programs\\thonny\\python.exe', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\\Users\\eezbe\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-izoqttv6\\dlib\\build\\lib.win32-3.7']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\eezbe\appdata\local\programs\thonny\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\eezbe\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-izoqttv6\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\eezbe\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-izoqttv6\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\eezbe\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-4ohgzi59\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\eezbe\appdata\local\programs\thonny\Include\dlib' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: `CMake` установлен?

Comment: Да, установлен, не в этом видимо проблема(

Comment: Создайте виртуальное окружение и там установите все нужные библиотеки. Если и так не будет работать, то приведите все использованные команды

Comment: Это точно весь вывод ошибки?

Comment: Да, весь.......

Comment: Попробуйте `sudo pip install dlib`, иногда это решает проблемы

Comment: у нас 3.11 что тогда сделать cp311 такого нету

Answer (score 2):

Причина ошибки явно указана тут:

> Python config failure: Python is 32-bit, chosen compiler is 64-bit

Добейтесь, чтобы студия, Python и все установленные модули были одной разрядности.

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install cmake
pip install dlib
```

Попробуйте так

Comment: Не получилось, к сожалению :(

Comment: Anton.dev Тебе сказал в чём ошибка!!! Вообще ответы не смотришь?

Answer (score 0):

убедитесь, что у вас установлен cmake и задан в переменной среды (куча роликов и статей по тому как установить cmake), а также советую установить Windows SDK
(поищите в интернете)

и можете установить boosts ( мало ли =3)

**НО ЕСЛИ ВЫ УВЕРЕНЫ, ЧТО ВСЕ ЭТО У ВАС ЕСТЬ, ТО..**

https://github.com/charlielito/install-dlib-python-windows в помощь.

В кратце перейди по ссылке: https://pypi.org/simple/dlib/
скачай dlib-19.21.0.tar.gz (правая кнопка, открыть в новом окне).
После распакуй и перейди в папку куда распаковал при помощи командной строки
и впиши `py -3 setup.py install` или если не получиться `python setup.py install`
(не забудьте, что вводить эту команду нужно находясь в папке)

вот скрины. Может так легче будет кому понять =3

переходите в папку и начинаете устанавливать setup.py через консоль при помощи команды отмеченной выше или в зоне с цифрой 2 на изображении
[image: dlib]

для того, чтобы удостовериться, что установка прошла успешна войдем в консоли в интерпретатор `py-3`  или `python` и импортируем модуль dlib, если ошибок нет, то все установка прошла успешна!
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Как я понял, версия `python`, должна совпадать с цифрами `dlib`, пример:

> python 3.8 --> dlib ...cp38...

и потом

> `pip install cmake, pip install wheel`

и скачанный отдельно файл `dlib` устанавливайте через команду

> `pip install *название*.whl.`

Я так установил на `win 10`.