# Проблема с установкой PyPi модуля

Tags: python, pip, модули, library

Всем привет. Не получается установить модуль dlib. Этот модуль очень нужен, но появляется такая ошибка(она будет ниже). Получается, что модуль битый? А как по другому его установить?

```
[roman@arch ~]$ pip install dlib
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting dlib
  Using cached dlib-19.20.0.tar.gz (3.2 MB)
Installing collected packages: dlib
    Running setup.py install for dlib ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-wiyt5fa6/dlib/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-wiyt5fa6/dlib/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-4e_v84b6/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers /home/roman/.local/include/python3.8/dlib
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-wiyt5fa6/dlib/
    Complete output (55 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    package init file 'dlib/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
    running build_ext
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/tmp/pip-install-wiyt5fa6/dlib/setup.py", line 120, in get_cmake_version
        out = subprocess.check_output(['cmake', '--version'])
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 411, in check_output
        return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 489, in run
        with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
        self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1702, in _execute_child
        raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'cmake'
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-wiyt5fa6/dlib/setup.py", line 223, in <module>
        setup(
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 144, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/command/install.py", line 545, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/tmp/pip-install-wiyt5fa6/dlib/setup.py", line 129, in run
        cmake_version = self.get_cmake_version()
      File "/tmp/pip-install-wiyt5fa6/dlib/setup.py", line 122, in get_cmake_version
        raise RuntimeError("\n*******************************************************************\n" +
    RuntimeError:
    *******************************************************************
     CMake must be installed to build the following extensions: dlib
    *******************************************************************
    
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-wiyt5fa6/dlib/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-wiyt5fa6/dlib/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-4e_v84b6/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers /home/roman/.local/include/python3.8/dlib Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: При чём тут битый модуль, английским по белому написано «CMake must be installed»

Comment: установил модуль cmake, аналогичная проблема

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1142699/394322

Comment: помогла установка через sudo, спасибо за попытку помощи!

Comment: @cxnnxrdvsh "roman@arch" означает, что у вас archlinux?